# Подгрузка только части полей модели Asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Нужно подгрузить только часть модели, например убрать пару полей, который не нужны в данный момент. Как это можно реализовать? Что-то типа этого не работает:

```
 _dbContext.News.Where(n => n.Id != newsId && n.IsActive).OrderBy(n => n.CreatedAt).Skip(1).Take(4).Select(n => _mapper.Map<PreviewNewsViewModel>(n)).ToListAsync();
```

PreviewNewsViewModel - такая же как модель, которую хочу вытащить, но без одного поля. Крашится именно на этой строчке.

Comment: зачем Skip(0)? Покажите пжлста ваши классы PreviewNewsViewModel и News, и как настроен AutoMapper.

Comment: в коде skip(1), видимо, когда правил - случайно поменял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как информации предоставлено в вопросе не так много, то есть предположение, что вам просто необходимо сказать AutoMapper-у, чтобы он при меппинге заигнорил поле, которое отсутствует в объекте PreviewNewsViewModel. Это можно сделать так

```
Mapper.CreateMap<NewsType, PreviewNewsViewModel>()
   .ForSourceMember(x => x.NewsField, y => y.Ignore());
```

> Как вытащить определенные столбцы?

Чтобы вытащить из БД не всю сущность целиком, а только определенные поля сущности, то вы можете в select-е создать [анонимный тип](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) со специфичными свойствами, которые должны быть вытащены из таблицы. 
Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
_dbContext.News.Where(n => n.Id != newsId && n.IsActive).Select(n => new {
   Id = n.Id
   Property1 = n.Property1
}).ToListAsync();
```

Это будет транслировано в SQL запрос примерно такой

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Property1 FROM News p WHERE p.Id != newsId && p.IsActive
```

Далее уже можете данную коллекцию с элементами анонимного типа преобразовать в  объекты типа PreviewNewsViewModel либо с помощью AutoMapper-а, либо руками.

Comment: Я маленько не про то. Автомаппер работает хорошо, суть в том, что я хочу из самой бд достать на одно поле меньше, ибо это поле - текст, длинный текст. Можно, конечно, в отдельную сущность вынести и хранить в той же таблице и не добавлять include, когда оно не нужно, но, возможно, есть способ проще.

Comment: @diablo123455, обновил ответ.